# Connection lost to target after .reload command

Tags: driver, windbg, wdk, kmdf, wdm

In WinDbg: File->Symbole File Path? I set the path to: 
`Srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`
After this path file setting I'm trying to make this example: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt269367
In section 5 step 2. when I type `.reload /f` the debugger lost connect to the 
target.
If I do not set the symbol file path, WinDbg breake up also at the same point.

For me it seems that windbg lost the connection to the target and do not get it 
established again. Even when I reboot the target system on the VM.

Can someone tell me what is going on and what I'm doing wrong or why this happen??

I am working with VMWare Player. My host and Target OS are Windows 10 Pro.
VMWare is configured to use network in NAT.
The Echo driver is successfully installed.

In following you can see the WinDbg log:

```
<Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.>

<Using NET for debugging>
<Opened WinSock 2.0>
<Waiting to reconnect...
<Connected to target 192.168.2.107 on port 50000 on local IP 192.168.2.107.>
<Connected to Windows 10 10586 x64 target at (Sat May 14 22:41:26.873 2016(UTC + 2:00)), ptr64 TRUE>
<Kernel Debugger connection established.>

<************* Symbol Path validation summary **************>
<Response                         Time (ms)     Location>
<Deferred                                       >
<Srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols>
<Symbol search path is: >
<Srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols>
<Executable search path is: >
<Windows 10 Kernel Version 10586 MP (1 procs) Free x64>
<Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS>
<Built by: 10586.306.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160422-1850>
<Machine Name:>
<Kernel base = 0xfffff801`68a78000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`68d56cd0>
<Debug session time: Sat May 14 22:41:25.623 2016 (UTC + 2:00)>
<System Uptime: 0 days 0:06:44.196>
<Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)>
<*******************************************************************************>
<*                                                                             *>
<*   You are seeing this message because you pressed either                    *>
<*       CTRL+C (if you run console kernel debugger) or,                       *>
<*       CTRL+BREAK (if you run GUI kernel debugger),                          *>
<*   on your debugger machine's keyboard.                                      *>
<*                                                                             *>
<*                   THIS IS NOT A BUG OR A SYSTEM CRASH                       *>
<*                                                                             *>
<* If you did not intend to break into the debugger, press the "g" key, then   *>
<* press the "Enter" key now.  This message might immediately reappear.  If it *>
<* does, press "g" and "Enter" again.                                          *>
<*                                                                             *>
<*******************************************************************************>
<nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:>
<fffff801`68bbfed0 cc              int     3>
<kd> !sym noisy>
<noisy mode - symbol prompts on>
<kd> .symfix>
<DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols>
<DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols>
<DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols>
<kd> .sympath+ C:\echo\kmdf\driver\AutoSync>
<DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path:cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\echo\kmdf\driver\autosync>
<DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path:cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\echo\kmdf\driver\autosync>
<Symbol search path is: srv*;C:\echo\kmdf\driver\AutoSync>
<Expanded Symbol search path is:cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\echo\kmdf\driver\autosync>

<************* Symbol Path validation summary **************>
<Response                         Time (ms)     Location>
<Deferred                                       srv*>
<OK                                             C:\echo\kmdf\driver\AutoSync>
<kd> .sympath>
<Symbol search path is: srv*;C:\echo\kmdf\driver\AutoSync>
<Expanded Symbol search path is: >
cache*;SRV*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\echo\kmdf\driver\autosync>
<>
<************* Symbol Path validation summary **************>
<Response                         Time (ms)     Location>
<Deferred                                       srv*>
<OK                                             C:\echo\kmdf\driver\AutoSync>
<kd> .reload /f>
<? Retry sending the same data packet for 64 times.>
<The transport connection between host and kernel debugger and target Windows seems lost.>
<please try resync with target, recycle the host debugger, or reboot the target Windows.>
<...Retry sending the same data packet for 128 times.>
<...Retry sending the same data packet for 192 times.>
<...Retry sending the same data packet for 256 times.>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Changed VM settings from Ethernet to COM.
I also changed the bcdedit debugsettings to COM Port by using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538143(v=vs.85).aspx) website to setup.
Now I can debugg and also reload symbols or the driver.

Comment: i had nat and i had problems of lost connections then as per google i changed the nat to host only and since then then the connections lost problems seems to have disappeared should be worth trying (net is favored it seems and is apparently faster than com as per google ) post back if was worth the effort if you tried and succeded

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial how to setup the environment? The one I have is not very good. When I tried it, it didn't worked for me. That is why I choose COM Port.

Comment: select host only radio button in vmware network setting , do ipconfig in host and locate the vmnet1 ipv4 address ping from target  if ok simply follow the documentation in windbg  bcdedit /debug on bcdedit /dbgsettings:net ipaddr:==xxx port  == XXX a key will be autogenerated use it in a batchfile in host  like windbg.exe" -k net:port=55555,Key=

Comment: Hello,thank you for your instructions. What I can not do is to ping the host from within the target. But I set the VMWare Player to "host" and now I can also debug with this method. Works great! So now I have to methods with wich I can debug. Only from within Visual Studio it is not possible. Anyway...